# How to understand hash wget ?

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux bash, here is a problem confusing me. I don't understand "hash wget". what's the purpose of it, why there should be a if check?

```
if [ ! -e text8 ]; then
  if **hash wget 2>/dev/null**; then
    wget http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip
  else
    curl -O http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip
  fi
  unzip text8.zip
  rm text8.zip
fi
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

if `wget` is available (in the `PATH`) the exit code for `hash wget` is 0, so the statement executes. The redirection `2>/dev/null` just redirects the error message when `wget` isn't found. Use `help hash` from bash prompt to read its info.

Comment: Thanks. :), it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

type help hash in command line.

XXXXX@ubuntu:~$ help hash
hash: hash [-lr] [-p 路径名] [-dt] [名称 ...]
    Remember or display program locations.

```
Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.

Options:
  -d        forget the remembered location of each NAME
  -l        display in a format that may be reused as input
  -p pathname   use PATHNAME as the full pathname of NAME
  -r        forget all remembered locations
  -t        print the remembered location of each NAME, preceding
        each location with the corresponding NAME if multiple
        NAMEs are given
Arguments:
  NAME      Each NAME is searched for in $PATH and added to the list
        of remembered commands.

Exit Status:
Returns success unless NAME is not found or an invalid option is given.
```